# Axios get in scroll pagination

Tags: scroll, axios, get

I am trying to do axios.get from Url, for retrieving data, but the page it's paginate with scroll pagination and I require all data .

How can retrieve all data?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about it,

1. If you have control over backend (API), modify the endpoint to return the whole list of data.
2. If that's not the case, loop the call, use scroll-id for further calls, maintain a list at UI side, and keep doing that until you get no data back.
   The scroll-id should be in body of the requests, like this,

> ```
>   {
>
>   "scroll_id" : 
>    "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ=="
>
>   }
> ```

Comment: await Axios.get("https://url.com",{ body:{"scroll_id":"DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ==" } } ).then(function(res){}.   I did this test, but when retrieve the data are the same, 10 per page, the page return only the first 10.  I am using node

Comment: I think you have to check your first scroll call, because that will set your size for all further calls.
{
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    "_doc"
  ]
}
try adding this in the body of the initial scroll call for like size 100.